# Cross reference table laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, laravel-5

Lets say there are three tables:

**categories**

```
id
```

**image_categories**

```
image_id
category_id
```

**images**

```
id
```

My idea was that an image has multiple categories so I made a cross reference table to attach a category to an image. In my cross table (image_categories) i create a reference with image_id to the image table and category_id to the category table

Now I need to find all images that belong to a category so in my class Category I add.

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Image', 'App\ImageCategory');
}
```

But I get an error that the column is not found.

```
 Unknown column 'image_categories.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `images`.*,
`image_categories`.`subcategory_id` from `images` inner join `image_categories`
on `image_categories`.`id` = `images`.`image_category_id` where 
`image_categories`.`subcategory_id` = 29)
```

if I look at the docs it says:

> **Has Many Through**
>
> The "has many through" relation provides a convenient short-cut for
> accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example,
> a Country model might have many Post through a User model. The tables
> for this relationship would look like this:

It sounds ideal for situations like this but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that table images has image_category_id column and image_categories has id? check again

Comment: @Akam nope my idea was that an image has multiple categories so i made a cross reference table to attach te category to an image. so in my cross table (image_categories) i create a reference with image_id to the image table and category_id to the category table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *category* has multiple *images* and *image* has multiple *categories*, here you have a **many to many** relationship, the name of your pivot table will be `category_image` (Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order) and it should contain a both ids of the two tables as `foreign key` (you can add more argument to the table if you need it).

So just follow instruction in laravel docummentation **[Many To Many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)** and it will work smoothly.

**Note :** If you Need to find all images that belong to a category so in your class `Category` define the `images()` function like bellow :

```
public function images(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, One kinda offtopic question. How dos laravel know plurals (category -> categories) has it a built in dictionary? For one project im using a different language.

Comment: I had to use belongsToMany instead of hasMany but it worked thanks to your link.

Comment: You are welcome guys any time. for the pluralization, they use class `Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer.php` read the source code if you want and you'll find how it actually works. see **[Pluralization in Localization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization#pluralization)** when you are using a different languages.

Comment: Hi @Sveb B you can suggest an edit and i'll accept it, thank you in advance.